# CSS add container after an absolute container that already have other 3 floated containers

Tags: html, css

I want to add an container after an absolute container that already have other 3 floated containers.

I've try clearfix and other CSS hacks without a chance.

You can see that my green container do not display first 6 lines.

**Please** add a CSS solution, without JS or jQuery solutions!

Here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusfv/2dgmzg6j/)

```css
#themaincontainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3 px solid #0A74B4;
    background-color: red;
    height: auto;
}
img.img1stdiv {
  max-width: 128px;
  max-height: 128px;
}
.my1floated {
    width: 15%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;  
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.my2floated {
    width: 56%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.my3floated {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 0;
}
#othercontainerafter {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="themaincontainer">
<div class="my1floated">
<img class="img1stdiv" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg/2000px-Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg.png">
</div>
  <div class="my2floated">
    <h2>My title here</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="my3floated">
    <h3>Support info here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="othercontainerafter">
The content of this container should be after themaincontainer who have inside that 3 floated containers.
  Line1
  <br>
  Line2
  <br>
  Line3
  <br>
  Line4
  <br>
  Line5
  <br>
  Line6
  <br>
  Line7
  <br>
  Line8
  <br>
  Line9
  <br>
  Line10
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floated element do not follow the natural document flow and therefore layout issues like this can occur. You can solve it by changing the CSS as follows:

```
#themaincontainer {
  float: left; /* Use this instead of position: absolute */
  width: 100%;
  border: 3 px solid #0A74B4;
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
}

#othercontainerafter {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left; /* Added */
  clear: both; /* To avoid elements will end up next to each other */
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/2dgmzg6j/2/)

Alternatively, use a flexbox instead of floats.

```css
#maincontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

#container-1 {
  border: 3 px solid #0A74B4;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

img.img1stdiv {
  max-width: 128px;
  max-height: 128px;
}

.my1floated {
  width: 15%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.my2floated {
  width: 56%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.my3floated {
  width: 25%;
}

#container-2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontainer">
  <div id="container-1">
    <div class="my1floated">
      <img class="img1stdiv" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg/2000px-Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="my2floated">
      <h2>My title here</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="my3floated">
      <h3>Support info here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="container-2">
    The content of this container should be after themaincontainer who have inside that 3 floated containers. Line1
    <br> Line2
    <br> Line3
    <br> Line4
    <br> Line5
    <br> Line6
    <br> Line7
    <br> Line8
    <br> Line9
    <br> Line10
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 10x for the answer. If the main container is floated left too and this main container already have 3 floated containers it display correctly other containers that come after the main container. Question is why?(Is this a CSS trick?).

Comment: Not a CSS trick, that's how floats work. Nowadays flexbox is becoming more popular than floats.

Comment: I have included an example using flexbox so you can compare.

Comment: I accepted this solution. I've learned something new today: 1. Float left main container(that already have 3 floated containers) let me display other containers after him. 2. Great informations about CSS flexbox. 10x!

Answer (score 0):

```
#themaincontainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3 px solid #0A74B4;
    background-color: red;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Change the position to relative, because absolute makes your div float. Relative position will force #themainDiv to come first and display the #otherDiv after it.

I have edited the style of #mainDiv above. just copy paste it.

Comment: 10x for the answer - I know that with position relative should work, but the main question itself is: ...after an absolute container.

Comment: If your want your display to be in row by row form then you should you relative, because absolute makes the attribute independent and disrupts the normal flow of your display. Anyways someone answered your question, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

> you use `width:100%` So no need `position:absolute`,When set to absolute or fixed, the element is removed completely from the normal flow of the document.
>
> Change `#themaincontainer` Like This:

```
#themaincontainer {
    position: absolute; <-----------------Removed
    width: 100%;
    border: 3  px solid #0A74B4;<----------3  px is Wrong,3px is correct.
    background-color: red;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;<-------------------Added
}
```

**Full Code :**

```css
#themaincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #0A74B4;
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img.img1stdiv {
  max-width: 128px;
  max-height: 128px;
}

.my1floated {
  width: 15%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;  
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.my2floated {
  width: 56%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.my3floated {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#othercontainerafter {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="themaincontainer">
  <div class="my1floated">
     <img class="img1stdiv" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg/2000px-Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg.png">
  </div>
  <div class="my2floated">
     <h2>My title here</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="my3floated">
     <h3>Support info here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="othercontainerafter">
The content of this container should be after themaincontainer who have inside that 3 floated containers.
Line1<br>Line2<br>Line3<br>Line4<br>Line5<br>Line6<br>Line7<br>Line8<br>Line9<br>Line10<br>
</div>
```

Comment: position: absolute; <----Removed => In this way I just cancel my own question: "... after an absolute container". Your solution works, like the other participants.

Comment: why you use `position: absolute`?

Comment: no need `position:absolute`,When set to absolute or fixed, the element is removed completely from the normal flow of the document.